# How to run nodejs app on specific port for the main domian on ubuntu?

Tags: php, node.js, ubuntu, port

I have the main app (PHP) on the main domain (https://www.mydomian.com)

i want to run nodejs app on the same domain but on another port like (https://www.mydomian.com:7070)
can any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what node.js web server you are using. I assume it's Express.js and in that case you just need to change the port in your `app.listen(PORT)` call to `7070`. Also check if your Ubuntu server has an iptable rule that blocks connections for certain ports.

Answer (score 0):

You can set port in the Terminal (I tested in Ubuntu 14 LTS)

For example,

**terminal**: set a new user environment variable, not permanently

`export PORT=7070`

**app.js**: read the new environment variable from node app

`console.log(process.env.PORT)`

**terminal**: run the node app and get the value

```
$ node app.js
7070
```

Answer (score 0):

you can manually set the port which is listening on in the `app.js` file (assumed you are using `express.js`)

```
var server = app.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('Ready on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

Tis will print on console `Ready on port 8080`.